# Update Qml during UI event

Tags: qt, qml

Since e.g. the `onClicked()` method of a button runs on the ui thread, the qml is not updated as long the `onclicked` method has finished. But what if there is some heavy computation that needs to be done in the onclicked method and i would like to display a loading indicator. As i know qml does not have async methods. so how can something like this be achieved

```
Button {
   width: 50
   height: 50

   onClicked: {
      loadingIndicator.visibile = true
      aHeavyFunction()
      loadingIndicator.visible = false
   }
}
```

Comment: what about http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-threading-example.html#workerscript ?

Comment: @Amfasis did not find this so far. thank you, i will have a try